# Android StaggeredGridLayoutManager offset bug

Tags: android, layout-manager, android-support-library, android-recyclerview, staggered-gridview

When you clear your **adapter** and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` - **StaggedGridLayoutManager** manager still has `mCachedStart/End` in `Span[]` instances. So when you add new items to adapter - layout manager draws items with **offset**, and this is a **huge problem**.

**EtsyStaggeredGridView** has method `resetToTop()` which clears all cached stuff and draws everything from scratch.

There are some workarounds:

- Call `layoutManager.onDetachedFromWindow(recyclerView, null)` after clearing an adapter
- Set **new** layout manager which is **bad**

[image: add 20 items to adapter]
[image: scroll a bit]
[image: remove items, notifyChanges, add 20 items]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some workarounds:

- Call `layoutManager.onDetachedFromWindow(recyclerView, null)` after clearing an adapter
- Set **new** layout manager which is **bad**

Comment: Well, this is an unusual question, yet it doesn't look like a question but the information given just solved the case, 
Call layoutManager.onDetachedFromWindow(recyclerView, null) after clearing an adapter 
Thank you, now offset problem is disappeared