# Large gap forms between RecyclerView items when scrolling down

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

I'm making a ToDo list app, and while testing it, for some reason, a huge gap forms between the items whenever I try to scroll down. It always happens whenever I Drag and Drop the items, but I don't see any errors with my ItemTouchHelper adapter and callback class. It would be awesome if you can help me out.

Before:
[image: Before]

After:
[image: After]

RecyclerAdapter.java

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends                                                                                                                                 

RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerVH> implements ItemTouchHelperAdapter{
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
ArrayList<Info> data;
Context context;

public RecyclerAdapter(Context context) {
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;
}

public void setData(ArrayList<Info> data) {
    this.data = data;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public RecyclerVH onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, viewGroup, false);
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("R.A onClick Owen", "onClick method triggered");
        }
    });
    RecyclerVH recyclerVH = new RecyclerVH(view);
    return recyclerVH;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerVH recyclerVH, int position) {
    Log.d("RecyclerView", "onBindVH called: " + position);

    final Info currentObject = data.get(position);
    // Current Info object retrieved for current RecyclerView item - USED FOR DELETE
    recyclerVH.listTitle.setText(currentObject.title);
    recyclerVH.listContent.setText(currentObject.content);

    /*recyclerVH.listTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Open new Activity containing note content
            Toast.makeText(this, "Opening: " + currentObject.title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });*/
}

public void deleteItem(int position) {
    DBInfo dbInfo = new DBInfo(context);
    dbInfo.deleteNote(data.get(position));
    // Deletes RV item/position's Info object

    data.remove(position);
    // Removes Info object at specified position

    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    // Notifies the RV that item has been removed
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

// This is where the Swipe and Drag-And-Drog methods come into place
@Override
public boolean onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
    // Swapping positions
    // ATTEMPT TO UNDERSTAND WHAT IS GOING ON HERE
    Collections.swap(data, fromPosition, toPosition);
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onItemDismiss(int position) {
    // Deleting item from RV and DB
    deleteItem(position);
}

class RecyclerVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    // OnClickListener is implemented here
    // Can also be added at onBindViewHolder above
    TextView listTitle, listContent;

    public RecyclerVH(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        listTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        listContent = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.content);

        listTitle.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Opening: Note" + getLayoutPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // PS NEVER ADD listTitle VARIABLE AS PUBLIC VARIABLE ABOVE WHICH IS GIVEN VALUE AT ONBINDVH
        // THIS IS BECAUSE THE VALUE WILL CHANGE IF ITEM IS ADDED OR DELETED
    }
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:gravity="bottom|end"
            android:onClick="addNote"
            android:src="@drawable/fab_ic_add"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

custom_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="@string/test"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/test"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you so much to whoever can help me out. I am pulling my hair out as I type.

EDIT: I have confirmed that it is not my ItemTouchHelper class that's the problem. (Tried running without it being called, problem still occurs.)
Also, it seems that when a dialog is shown and the keyboard brought up, the RecyclerView in the background resolves the problem by itself. After dialog is removed, the problem repeats (i.e. Scrolling puts massive space between items)

Comment: Remove Match_parent with in the height of relative layout in the custom.XML file.

Answer (score 37):

change in Recycler view **match_parent** to **wrap_content**:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Also change in item layout xml

Make parent layout height **match_parent** to **wrap_content**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

Answer (score 6):

This happened to me many times!

All you need to do is... make layout_height of row file wrap_content and your problem solved..

`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Its because you are using **match_parent** in height of root view of the row item in your vertically oriented listview/recyclerview. When you use that the item expands completely wrt to its parent.
Use **wrap_content** for height when the recyclerview is *vertically* oriented and for width when it is *horizantally* oriented.

Answer (score 0):

i have this problem and i just use

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

for parent of every item.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid taking the view in item layout with a container like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<data/>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?android:listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

as in this case `match_parent` will do its work and the problem will still remain! Rather take it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?android:listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</layout>
```

[Note: Above code has data binding attached to it, don't use `<layout>` & `<data>` tags if not using data binding]

Other than this, if you must use any view group containers, than take a look the height and width attributes in the container, and try change those from `match_parent` to `wrap_content`. That should resolve the issue. For more transparency, one can try giving background colours and see through it to identify actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record: Since in my case we had to implement some "superfancy UI" with overlapping RecyclerView and blur effect toolbar, I had to get rid of `clipToPadding="false"` within `RecyclerView`-xml.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/height_toolbar"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/height_bottom_bar_container"
  //android:clipToPadding="false" <-- remove this flag!
  android:scrollbars="vertical"
/>
```

`paddingTop`and `paddingBottom` worked, but we replaced it with some GapViews(empty views, with height of paddingTop and paddingBottom)

Answer (score 0):

if someone is using | recyclerViewObject.setHasFixedSize(true);

try removing it, It was causing the issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting your Viewgroup holding the recyclerview to wrap content

Comment: if that doesn't work then your recyclerview layout file   android:layout_height="wrap_content"